# Angular 6 - How to generate visual structure of components

Tags: angular, typescript, components, hierarchy

I have just started out a new Angular 6 app and I already have a lot of components.

For documentation purpose, I was wondering if there exists a good tool for creating a visual overview of the component hierarchy based on the root of the application.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: Have you heard about [Augury](https://augury.rangle.io/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [Compodoc](https://compodoc.app/guides/getting-started.html) for a while and it has everything I need to generate documentation resources. I suggest to check it out

Comment: It looks really nice, I can definitely use that. Thanks a lot! :)